# Xcode Simulator app opened 3 times and crash

Tags: appium-ios

i have this capabilities
xcode 9

```
appium server 1.8.1
    {
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "platformVersion": "11.3",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 8 Plus",
  "app": "/Users/faroukrahem/Downloads/Amazon.ipa",
  "udid": "913FD18F-FF62-425D-B8B3-DB22CDE8DD50",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "xcodeOrgId": "U2CURAR7S5",
  "xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer",
  "noReset": true
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
"xcodeOrgId": "U2CURAR7S5",
  "xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer",

Orgid & SiginID to be specified in Xcode config file::

Webdriver agent need to be successfully running on device Try to configure Webdriver agent and Developer ID ::
```

Open the existing the WebDriver Agent (double click on WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj)

On top of Xcode you File > New> File , then you will an pop up something like this

Select OSX->.Other-> Select Configuration settings file.

Paste the following things in newly created file.

DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = xxxxxxxxx

CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer

Development team is Team ID which your developer should be able to provide . Dont change the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY.

In device.propoerties file add this

xcodeConfigFile=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Config.xcconfig

In ConfigCapa.java file add this

capabilities.setCapability(“xcodeConfigFile”,emulatorProp.getProperty(“xcodeConfigFile”));

Open terminal go to

$ cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/

$ mkdir -p Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle

sh ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh –d

Go to terminal type

xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination ‘id=DeviceID’ test Last line on build output above command should be Listening on USB. Then you are all set!

brew install libimobiledevice –HEAD

To run appium type appium &

To find version type appium — v